# Trying to display images from array using javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

I am trying to display the images I have inside my image array in a table cell. I have already tried it with a for-loop and a foreach-loop. The images are shown, but it is either that all the images are displayed in each cell or only the last image is displayed in every cell.

This is the first loop I tried:

[This code causes all the images to show up in one cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3OD5.png)

[This code causes the last picture from the array to show up in every cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D79Og.png)

This is my whole loop:

```
map.forEach((values, keys) =>{
                      var table = 
                      document.getElementById('table');
                      var row = table.insertRow();
                      var cellImage = row.insertCell(0);
                      var cellArtist = row.insertCell(1);
                      var cellTitle = row.insertCell(2);
                      cellArtist.innerHTML = keys;
                      cellTitle.innerHTML = values;

                      var image = 
                      document.createElement("img");
                      for(let i = 0; i < mapImg.length; i++){     
                                            
                          image.src = mapImg[i];

                          cellImage.appendChild(image);
                      }
})
```

[The `map` contains this data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPZcr.png)

I am trying to populate the cells with the keys and the values from my array `map` . The Images are stored in the array `mapImg`.

```
var map = new Map();
var mapImg = [];
```

If anyone has an idea I would be very greatful.

**Update:**
I had to change the positioning of the loops and I had to put `outerHTML` to the appended Image.
Now the code to show the images looks like this

```
var image = document.createElement("img");
image.src = mapImg[i];              
cellImage.appendChild(image).outerHTML;
```

Comment: What does the array `map` contain? Try adding `([ values, keys ]) => {` or `({ values, keys }) => {` at the forEach, otherwise the `keys` variable is the index position of `value` in your array `map` not the nested key value you might have.

Comment: the array map contains songartists as keys and songtitles as values. 
If i add your suggestion I still get the same picture in each cell.

Comment: You are creating a cell where you put all the images. Normally, I would expect you to create add a singl3 cell per image ...

Comment: Please provide an example of what `map` contains.

Comment: So I would have to create a new cell for every Image and append each Image-Tag to the newly created cell?

Comment: Is the `index` at `mapImg` equal to the index of `map`? (`mapImg[0]` is the picture for `map[0]`?) -- What your code currently does is: for every entry of `map`, add all images from `mapImg` (or the last one, with a loop like the one in the example here) to every entry of `map`.

Comment: Yes, it would have the same index i think but since map is buitld like a hashmap, I am not sure if I would be able to get the numerical index of de values.

Comment: You can get the position with an iteration over [map.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries#examples). But i would recommend changing the map to an Array or Object and using the same structure like the mapImg has. That would be a lot easier to understand, read and handle. Otherwise you could create some kind of fake index defining a var outside the forEach and increase it during the loop. Like `var = 0; map.forEach((...) => { ... mapImg[var] ; var++; }` but it's not guaranteed that the indexPosition would be the same.